# Problems with deleting rown in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have one problem that i can't resolve.When i make this code and run it, it always delete last row of mysql database.Please help me guys.Ty :D

I had some problems publishing code so u can find it here jsfiddle.net/xhCLz/
under "javascript" box.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test_mysql");
$postid1 ="1";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $ime=$row['name'];
    $prezime=$row['lastname'];
    $id_number=$row['id'];
  echo $ime. " " . $prezime. " " .$id_number. "<form action='' method='post'>

<input type='hidden' name='id_number_send' value='<?php echo $id_number?>'/>
<input type='submit' name='send_value' value='delete' />
</form>";

  }
  if(isset($_POST['send_value']))
{

    $delete_row = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM test_mysql WHERE id='$id_number'");
    echo $id_number;

}
```

Comment: Your delete is outside the loop.  And after the loop, the only value in $id_number will be the last one.  Its kind of obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get id from the POST, instead you use the id assign the last time your loop execute.

You have to get the id of the row you want to delete from the `$_POST` variable (`$_POST['id_number_send']`) and sanitise your data before use it in the query to prevent SQL injection ([mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)).

you should also do your delete before the loop if you want display all rows without the deleted one.

```
if(isset($_POST['send_value']))
{
    $deleteId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id_number_send']);
    $delete_row = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM test_mysql WHERE id='$deleteId'");
    echo "ID number: " . $deleteId . " has been deleted.<br><br>";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test_mysql");
$postid1 ="1";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $ime=$row['name'];
    $prezime=$row['lastname'];
    $id_number=$row['id'];
  echo $ime. " " . $prezime. " " .$id_number. "<form action='' method='post'>

<input type='hidden' name='id_number_send' value='$id_number' />
<input type='submit' name='send_value' value='delete' />
</form>";

  }
```

Comment: `$deleteId= mysqli_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['id_number_send']);` are you sure about that?

Comment: full of errors :/ edited, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I removed `<?php echo` and `?`> from the hidden field in an edit, since it's already being echo'ed and would not have worked. Your code/answer works now (I tested it myself also). **+1** ;-)

Comment: Thanks u dude! i love u so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The very last time your while loop runs, it assigns the last ID it found to the variable $id_number:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ime=$row['name'];
    $prezime=$row['lastname'];
    $id_number=$row['id'];
    //etc.
```

So instead of having your DELETE query use that variable, which will always be the last number it found, you should use the variable from the submitted form, which is a $_POST variable:

```
$delete_row = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM test_mysql WHERE id='$_POST['id_number_send']'");
```